# Catch exception and reset windows form C#

Tags: c#, forms, exception

I'm currently working on my first assignment using windows forms in visual studio and have been a little stuck.

I'm trying to test if a user input is numeric, and if the input is not numeric, a little message box pops up and alerts the user. (I've done this part). The issue I'm having is the and error continues to pop in visual studio

[image: error]

Is this a formatting issue? Should I reformat my code? As you can probably see I am new the C# (and programming).

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace wtgCalculator {
public partial class Form1 : Form {

   const double maleratio = 0.536;
   const double femaleratio = 0.492;


    public Form1() {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    private void WaistNumericCheck() {

        double waist;
        string inpwaist = heighttextbox.Text;

        if (double.TryParse(inpwaist, out waist)) {

            MessageBox.Show("Value must be numeric");      //this is where the problem is



        }                                    
    }

    private void HeightNumericCheck() {          
        //todo
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        //record inputs to variables
        WaistNumericCheck();
        HeightNumericCheck();
        double height = double.Parse(heighttextbox.Text);
        double waist = double.Parse(waisttextbox.Text);             
        //check is inputs are within boundry          
        CheckDimensions(height, waist);
        //test
       // ShowResult(height, waist);               

    }


    private void CheckLimits(double height, double waist) {

        double result = CalculateRatio(height, waist);

        if (Female.Checked) {

            if (result < femaleratio) {

                MessageBox.Show("Your risk of obesity related cardiovasular is low");

            }

            if (result > femaleratio) {

                MessageBox.Show("Your risk of obesity related to cardiovascular is high");

            }

        }

        if (Male.Checked) {

            if (result < maleratio) {

                MessageBox.Show("Your risk of obesity related cardiovasular is low");

            }

            if (result > maleratio) {

                MessageBox.Show("Your risk of obesity related cardiovasular is High");


            }
        }


        //testing
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());

    }

    private void ShowResult(double height, double waist) {

        //double result = CalculateRatio(height, waist);

        //if (Female.Checked) {

        //    if (result < femaleratio) {

        //        MessageBox.Show("Your risk of obesity related cardiovasular is low");

        //    }

        //    if (result > femaleratio) {

        //        MessageBox.Show("Your risk of obesity related to cardiovascular is high");

        //    }

        //}

        //if (Male.Checked) {



        //}


    }

    private static void CheckDimensions(double height, double waist) {

        if (height <= 120) {
            MessageBox.Show("Height must be greater than 120cm");
        }

        if (waist <= 60) {
            MessageBox.Show("Waist must be greater than 60cm");
        }    
    }


    private void Gender_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        button1.Enabled = true;                        
    }

    private static double CalculateRatio(double height, double waist) {

       double finalratio = waist / height;
       return finalratio; 

    }



}
}
```

Thanks again, and let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really handling this correctly. `.Parse()` is **supposed** to throw an exception if the value cannot be converted. **The whole point of `.TryParse()` is to avoid that.** So, your methods need to be cleaned up and edited to actually accomplish something:

```
private bool WaistNumericCheck(out double waist) 
{
    bool canParse = double.TryParse(heighttextbox.Text, out waist);

    if ( !canParse ) {
        MessageBox.Show("Value must be numeric");
    }  

    return canParse;                      
}

private bool HeightNumericCheck(out double height)
{          
    // todo -> same pattern as above
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    double height = 0, waist = 0;
    if( WaistNumericCheck(waist) && HeightNumericCheck(height) )
    {                    
        CheckDimensions(height, waist);

        /* ... the rest of your code */
    }              
}
```

This modifies your test methods to return a true/false based on whether the parse was successful, and `out`s your parsed variables so that you don't have to parse them again.

I suggest at some point that you review the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx